# Efficient Cython for large matrix creation/manipulation

Tags: python, performance, matrix, 64-bit, cython

I have been trying to speed up a section of code that creates and manipulates a very large matrix of data (approx. 15,000 x 15,000; type double). For now, I don't think the size of the matrix is that important because I do not see speedup even for a small 10 x 10 matrix (in fact, the compiled cython code is slower than pure python for small matrices, whereas the time is nearly identical between cython and python for the large matrices). Please be patient with me, as I have only been coding python for a week (newly converted from Matlab) and I am only a humble chemical engineer.

The goal of the code is to take a 1D array (length L) as input, for a example:

```
[ 16.66  16.85  16.93  16.98  17.08  17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72]
```

And produce a matrix (height L, width L-1) as output:

```
[[ 16.66  16.85  16.93  16.98  17.08  17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67]
 [ 16.85  16.93  16.98  17.08  17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72]
 [ 16.93  16.98  17.08  17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72   0.  ]
 [ 16.98  17.08  17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72   0.     0.  ]
 [ 17.08  17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72   0.     0.     0.  ]
 [ 17.03  17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72   0.     0.     0.     0.  ]
 [ 17.09  16.76  16.67  16.72   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  ]
 [ 16.76  16.67  16.72   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  ]
 [ 16.67  16.72   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  ]
 [ 16.72   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  ]]
```

I hope it is clear from the example above and from the code below what I am trying to achieve. The algorithm needs to scale to very large matrices, which it currently does without error, it's just slow!

Here is my cython code:

```
from scipy.sparse import spdiags
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sfmat(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] data):
    cdef int h = data.shape[0]   
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] m = np.zeros([h, h-1])
    m = np.flipud(spdiags(np.tril(np.tile(data,[h-1,1]).T,0),range(1-h,1), h, h-1).todense())
    return m
```

I also tried more verbose code, which may be more clear to read:

```
from scipy.sparse import spdiags
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sfmat(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] data):
    assert data.dtype == DTYPE
    cdef int h = data.shape[0]   
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] m = np.zeros([h, h-1], dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] s1 = np.zeros([h, h-1], dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] s2 = np.zeros([h, h-1], dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] s3 = np.zeros([h, h-1], dtype=DTYPE)

    s1 = np.tile(data,[h-1,1]).T
    s2 = np.tril(s1,0)
    s3 = spdiags(s2,range(1-h,1), h, h-1).todense()
    m = np.flipud(s3)
    return m
```

Any help with the cython implemenation would be very much appreciated. If there is any other way to speed up this algorithm, that would help too.
Thank you for any help!

Because I am new to this, here are more details, which may or may not be preventing me from speeding this up. 
I am running 64 bit Windows 7 Pro, and compiling the cython code successfuly using the Windows SDK C/C++ compiler. (I followed the directions on github [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows) with success). The simple "hello world" cython examples compile fine and run fine in 64 bit mode, and the code above also compiles and runs with no errors. For manipulation of the entire 15,000 x 15,000 matrix, 64bit architecture is required, or at least I believe so, because running the code after compiling for 32bit resulted in a memory error. For this question, please assume that breaking up the matrix into smaller chunks is not possible.
Please let me know if there is any other information required to answer this question.

Cheers, scientistR

**UPDATE**

I thought that avoiding for loops would be the best approach, however, spdiags is the main bottleneck. Thus, a new algorithm works better (4x improvement on my computer):

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sfmat(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] data):
     cdef int i
     cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] m = np.zeros([data.shape[0], data.shape[0]-1])
     for i in range(data.shape[0]-1):
         m[:,i] = np.roll(data,-i);
     return m
```

But Cython does not offer any improvement over pure Python. Please help. As the commentators have pointed out, there may not be a way to improve this, besides a more optimizes algorithm, but I am hopeful. Thanks! Also, is there a faster algorithm, cython or python?

Comment: Cython won't give you a speed up here, since you're using python/numpy functions mostly. Although it's not directly part of your question, I'd like to know why you create this matrix, since the information it contains seem very redundant... Where do you need to use this matrix?

Comment: Agree with @DavidZwicker, you're probably better off optimizing the code that *consumes* this matrix by making it work with the original array instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. I agree with you, optimizing the code that consumes the matrix is probably the best route. I originally wrote the algorithm this way for matlab, where I could perform linear regression on each column of data simultaneously without using for loops! (linear algebra is amazing) Moving from loops to one matrix increased the speedup a lot, but now I am stuck on how to improve it further. To fully clarify: Where do I need this matrix? I need this matrix for rolling (frame shifting) linear regression of an array.

Comment: I found a better algorithm (see update in question), however it is still slow in cython (no improvement over pure python). I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit of an old question, but no question should be left unanswered `:)`. I was able to speed up your Cython code by about 8x by using straightforward for-loops (which are actually fast in Cython), for array size of 7000.. Note by the way that your implementation using `np.roll` does not produce the array that you want (!), but I used that function to compare timings with.

*Edited code to use Typed Memoryviews and `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros`*

```
def sfmat(double[:] data):
     cdef int n = data.shape[0]
     cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] out = np.empty((n, n-1))
     cdef double [:, :] out_v = out  # "typed memoryview"

     cdef int i, j
     for i in range(n-1):
        out_v[0, i] = data[i]

     for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(n-i):
            out_v[i, j] = data[i+j]
        for j in range(n-i, n-1):
            out_v[i, j] = 0.
     return out
```

Unfortunately, the Cython effort is only ~1.2x faster than running the following code in a regular Python session:

```
def sfmat(data):
    n = len(data)
    out = np.empty((n, n-1))
    out[0, :] = data[:n-1]
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        out[i, :n-i] = data[i:]
        out[i, n-i:] = 0
    return out
```

However as already discussed in the comments, blowing up your original fairly small matrix in this way is probably not the most efficient way to tackle your actual, overall problem anyway. If all you wanted to do initially was avoid using for-loops, in Cython there's simply no need to do that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound naive, but we all know that C, C++, and Python are "row-major" languages, right?  Matlab (and Fortran) are "column-major." I'm sure that you've already tried reversing `i` and `j`, but just wanted to mention it, just in case no one thought of trying that.